# SubSonic 3 ActiveRecord Fluent Query Multiple Join

Tags: join, subsonic, subsonic3

I'm trying to do a multiple join to a second column that is referenced from the first join.  So in effect find out which stores the product is in.

```
var q = new MyDB().SelectColumns(Store.NameColumn)
.From<Product>()
.InnerJoin<Shelf>(Product.ShelfIdColumn, Shelf.IdColumn)
.InnerJoin<Store>(Shelf.StoreIdColumn, Store.IdColumn)
.Where(Product.IdColumn).IsEqualTo(5);
```

The problem is that SubSonic is trying to join the Store table directly to the Product table.  I see in the source the comment:

```
//the assumption here is that the FromTable[0] is the table to join from
```

So every join is going to be attempted on the Product table.  2.1 had the option of passing in qualified names for the join.  Is there a way around this or should I start writing my own fix to allow me to pass in qualified names again?

Comment: Subsonic? Is this project still active? It was very promising until Rob got hired by Microsoft...